# SAS assigning binary values if variable matches in first instance for 'n' times for unsorted data

Tags: sorting, hash, sas, hashtable

I hope you guys are well.
**DATA:** The input data is unsorted and hence I am using hash tables to take the input data, do some iterations, sort and then output. Sorting the original table prior to any iterations (using proc sort) would be a time-consuming effort. If there is no other option, then I will need to sit down for the gruesome sorting approach.

What I want: I am trying to enumerate a table variable "answer" with binary values (0/1) if variable filter = "Y" for the next 6 month observations with the same client. In some instances, the client is missing from some monthly observations eg: client FG5151 is missing from September and October 2006. In short if variable filter "Y" then this observation and the next 6 months observations for same client should be assigned variable "answer" eq 1, else 0.

```
data have;
input client $ dates date9. filter $;
datalines ;
Fg5151 28.Feb.06 N
Fg5151 31.Mar.06 N
Fg5151 30.Apr.06 N
Fg5151 31.May.06 Y
Fg5151 30.Jun.06 N
Fg5151 31.Jul.06 Y
Fg5151 31.Aug.06 N
Fg5151 30.Nov.06 N
Fg5151 31.Dec.06 N
Fg5151 01.Jan.07 N
A101 28.Feb.06 N
A101 31.Mar.06 N
A101 30.Apr.06 Y
A101 31.May.06 N
A101 30.Jun.06 N
A101 31.Jul.06 N
ABC123 31.Mar.06 N
;



data want;
input client $ dates date9. filter $ answer;
datalines ;
A101 28.Feb.06 N 0
A101 31.Mar.06 N 0
A101 30.Apr.06 Y 1
A101 31.May.06 N 1
A101 30.Jun.06 N 1
A101 31.Jul.06 N 1
ABC123 31.Mar.06 N 0
Fg5151 28.Feb.06 N 0
Fg5151 31.Mar.06 N 0
Fg5151 30.Apr.06 N 0
Fg5151 31.May.06 Y 1
Fg5151 30.Jun.06 N 1
Fg5151 31.Jul.06 Y 1
Fg5151 31.Aug.06 N 1
Fg5151 30.Nov.06 N 1
Fg5151 31.Dec.06 N 1
Fg5151 01.Jan.07 N 0
;
```

I have written both a hash statement and a data step statement. I dont know how to approach this problem:

```
/* data step approach */
data want;
  set have;
  retain answer c;
  if _n_=1 or lag(client) ne client then do;
    answer=0;
    c=0;
  end;
  if filter="Y" then do;
    call symput('xdate',dates);
    answer=1;
    c=1;
  end;
  else if answer=1 then c=c+1;
  if (intnx("month",dates,6,"same")) then do;
    answer=0;
    c=0;
  end;
run;
/* hash method approach */

data _null_;
    set have end=last;
    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        length newdate 8 answer 8 c 8;
        format newdate ddmmyy10.;
        declare hash hs(ordered: "a",hashexp: 9);
        hs.defineKey("client","dates");
        hs.defineData("client","dates","filter","answer","c");
        hs.defineDone();
    end;
    rc = hs.find();
    by client dates notsorted;
    if rc ne 0 then do;
        retain answer c;
        if _n_=1 or lag(client) ne client then do;
            answer=0;
            c=0;
        end;
        if filter="Y" then do;
            answer=1;
            c=1;
            hs.add();
        end;
        else if answer=1 then c=c+1;
        if (intnx("month",dates,6,"same")) then do;
            answer=0;
            c=0;
            hs.replace();
        end;
        hs.replace();
    end;
    if last eq 1 then do;
hs.output(dataset:
        "not_working");
    end;
run;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thank you.
regards,
S

Comment: Is it "next six iterations" no matter what the time difference is, or is it "next six calendar months" no matter how many iterations?  Your example and your text don't 100% sync to me.

Comment: Hello joe,it is next 6 calendar months

Comment: How big of a dataset are you talking, and how many rows with `flag=y` are there proportional to the dataset?  How fast does this need to be?  How many rows per client are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `PROC FORMAT`.  This has a sort in it, but only of the filter='Y' folks, so hopefully that's minimal; and it's actually unnecessary if you are confident your data is grouped (but not sorted) by client (ie, you can skip it, it will not delete anything), and in fact with the `m` option being used anyway (to avoid worrying about collisions) you probably can skip it regardless.

This is not super-fast necessarily, because it uses `putn` function instead of `put` statement.  You will have to see how it performs on larger datasets.

The idea here is we construct a format that defines the range of 'Y' for each record, and uses `hlo='o'` option to define the rest of the ragne as `n`.

```
data for_fmt;
  set have;
  by client notsorted;
  if filter='Y' then do;
    start = dates;
    end = intnx('Month',dates,5,'s');
    hlo=' m';
    fmtname=cats(client,'F');
    label='Y';
    output;
  end;
  if last.client then do;
    fmtname=cats(client,'F');
    call missing(of start end);
    hlo='om';
    label='N';
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sort nodupkey data=for_fmt;
  by fmtname start;
run;


proc format cntlin=for_fmt;
quit;

data want;
  set have;
  answer = putn(dates,cats(client,'F'));
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Joe. Much appreciated.